# Hide overlaypanel when I click outside the box or in the box Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created an OverlayPanel like component so there I can put more clicks or something else.
But when I click outside the overlay or in the overlay this does not exit stays always there, it is dissapear only when I click in button what I have writed.

[Here is the link of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfvmjl)

I have like this the overlaPanel created.

```
<div class="dropdown">   
  <div (click)="toggle()" class="body">
    <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="active" class="popup" >
    <ng-content select="[popup]"></ng-content>
  </div>    
</div>

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

export class OverlaypanelComponent implements OnInit {   
  active = false;

  constructor() {         
  }

  offClickHandler(event: any) {
    if (event['.body'] && event['.popup'] === true) {
      this.active = false;
    }
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  toggle() {
    this.active = !this.active;
  }

  close() {
    this.active = !this.active;
  }

}
```

And this is when I call this component

```
 <app-overlaypanel>
        <div body [ngClass]="[getBackgroundColorClass(),clazz]" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o edit-block"></div>
        <div class="overlayPopup" popup>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="openTechnicalEditDialog({cluster: cluster, type: clazz})">Edit</div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="delete()">Delete</div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="openTechnicalEditDialog({appendToParentId: cluster.id})" *ngIf="cluster.level <= 9">Append</div>
          <div

 class="dropdown-menu-item" (click)="clicked.emit()">Assign</div>
    </div>
  </app-overlaypanel>
```

Comment: can you add your code in stackblits

Comment: @Chellappan I will try but I am not to good in stackblitz

Comment: @Chellappan Here is the stackblitz what I have created.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfvmjl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to close the drop down when you click outside of your menu you can use host listener to know whether you clicked outside or not

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickedOutside($event){

    this.active=false;
  }
```

I have attached the example check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5p5d1b

Comment: And how can I make if I click in the menu the same should happen the menu is hidden ?

Comment: do want to hide if you click dropdown item?

Comment: Yes I want the both if you click out or in hide the menu

Comment: can you check this link again  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5p5d1b

Comment: One question does the hostListener slows down the performance of the web application, because now some components are working slower...

Comment: it is going very slow the web app with this HostListener without it it works fast but the outside click and inside then not working

Comment: no it will not because your not doing any heavy logic inside your hostlistner if you feel it is slow your app the seperate the outside click as diretive

Comment: How can I do this to seperate like directive, because I have create a console.log andfor every click that I do in the web app it calls the method of HostListener more than 1000 times

Comment: this is the only hack as far as i know to click outside if you create separate directive also since we are targeting document:click it will call again and again

Comment: Is there any way to do only for this component to call this click ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174863/discussion-between-zhuniqia-and-chellappan).

Answer (score 3):

I know the question says Angular 4 but incase if someone is wondering how can we do the same with latest version of angular.

Now Anglar Material overlay comes with such directive and event listener.

```
              <ng-template
              cdkConnectedOverlay
              [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
              [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
              [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="isOpen"
              [cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass]="'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop-cs'"
              (backdropClick)="isOpen = !isOpen"
                >   
                content to be shown on overlay
            </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-click-outside` module as described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside
working with me fine in angular 8