# In ngx-bootstrap dropdown, outside tap does not dismiss dropdown. Is there any solution?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

Outside click (tap) to dismiss dropdown does not work on iOS (Safari or Chrome) on physical device.

In regular bootstrap, outside tap to dismiss works fine so it seems surprising that it does not work in ngx-bootstrap.

Does anyone know any workaround?

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: The issue can be seen on the demo itself: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282595/hide-overlaypanel-when-i-click-outside-the-box-or-in-the-box-angular-4/51283495#51283495

Comment: Thanks but that is not the issue. The click event works fine on pc browsers but on iPhone, the click event seems to be different than the tap and the tap does not close the dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that iOS only registers click events on elements that have cursor: pointer or an onClick handler. So I just added cursor:pointer to all elements when device is touch. That seems to be working fine for now